# deleting a row in listView not working as expected

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I'm currently trying to delete a row in my listView when the user clicks on the X button in my custom row view. sadly, it doesn't seem to work when I try to use the `remove()` function. Could I have setup the ListView's data type incorrectly? Currently it inflates a linearLayout with 2 buttons, and an ImageButton. The ImageButton is the X button. Here is the adapter. It extends an arrayAdapter of Classes objects. (They just hold 2 strings) so `new Classes("", "");` Whether I tell the remove function to delete position 0, 1, 2, etc. it doesn't matter. It will always delete the last position in the list. What am I doing wrong?

```
public PlannerListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> rubric,
        SortedMap<String, String> currentTerms, ArrayList<String> termList, ArrayList<Classes> listItems) {
    super(context, R.layout.schedule_planner_list_item);

    this.context = context;
    this.rubricList = rubric;
    this.currentTerms = currentTerms;
    this.termList = termList;
    this.rubricList = rubric;
    courseHandler = new CourseHandler();
    courseDataTask = new GetCourseData();
    this.listItems = listItems;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

}
static class ClassViewHolder {
    private Button rubric;
    private Button course;
    private ImageButton clearView;

    //pub constructor
    ClassViewHolder(Button rubric, Button course, ImageButton clearView) {
        this.rubric = rubric;
        this.course = course;
        this.clearView = clearView;
    }

    /**
     * @return the rubric
     */
    public Button getRubric() {
        return rubric;
    }
    /**
     * @param rubric the rubric to set
     */
    public void setRubric(Button rubric) {
        this.rubric = rubric;
    }
    /**
     * @return the course
     */
    public Button getCourse() {
        return course;
    }
    /**
     * @param course the course to set
     */
    public void setCourse(Button course) {
        this.course = course;
    }

    /**
     * @return the clearView
     */
    public ImageButton getClearView() {
        return clearView;
    }

    /**
     * @param clearView the clearView to set
     */
    public void setClearView(ImageButton clearView) {
        this.clearView = clearView;
    }
}


/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.widget.ArrayAdapter#getCount()
 */
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return listItems.size();
}



/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.widget.ArrayAdapter#getItem(int)
 */
@Override
public Classes getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return listItems.get(position);
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.widget.ArrayAdapter#getPosition(java.lang.Object)
 */
@Override
public int getPosition(Classes item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return listItems.indexOf(item);
}

public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 1;
}


/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.widget.ArrayAdapter#getView(int, android.view.View, android.view.ViewGroup)
 */
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    final Button rubric;
    final Button course;
    final ImageButton clearView;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.schedule_planner_list_item, null);
        rubric = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.rubric_spinner);
        course = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.course_spinner);
        clearView = (ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.clear_courseRubric_view);
        convertView.setTag(new ClassViewHolder(rubric, course, clearView));
    }
    else {
        ClassViewHolder viewHolder = (ClassViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        rubric = viewHolder.getRubric();
        course = viewHolder.getCourse();
        clearView = viewHolder.getClearView();
    }

    rubric.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RubricArray = rubricList.toArray(RubricArray);
            //Toast.makeText(context, rubricList.get(0), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            AlertDialog.Builder rubricDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            rubricDialog.setTitle("Pick a Rubric");
            rubricDialog.setItems(RubricArray, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, final int which) {
                    RubricString = RubricArray[which];
                    rubric.setText(RubricString);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    currentSubject = RubricString;
                    courseList.clear();
                    CourseArray = courseList.toArray(CourseArray);
                    courseDataTask.execute();
                    courseHandler = new CourseHandler();
                    courseDataTask = new GetCourseData();
                }
            });

            rubricDialog.show();
        }

    });
    course.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            AlertDialog.Builder courseDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            courseDialog.setTitle("Pick a Course") ;
            courseDialog.setItems(CourseArray, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    CourseString = CourseArray[which];

                    course.setText(CourseString);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });

            courseDialog.show();

        }
    });

    clearView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listItems.remove(listItems.lastIndexOf(v);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: I think the remove is not working because it doesn't find the view you are passing in the method lastIndexOf, that method expects Classes and u are passing a View, have you tried hard coding an index?

Comment: yes I have. It still deletes the last View every time. If I put in remove(0) it will remove the last position.

Comment: That's fine, the issue is you are looking for a button in your findlastindex method, is a list of buttons what you have in the array? Because onclick returns in view a reference to the clicked button

Comment: no..I'm saying if I replace lastIndexof(v) with 0 it doesn't work either. the lastIndexOf I can delete. I just threw that in there. I want it to delete the position I specify.

Answer (score 0):

Because i don't have enough reputation to comment on your question i write this.
I didn't test your code but may be problem is in finding index of clicked view.
I'm asking why you don't use position to remove list item like,

```
listItems.remove(position); then, 
notifyDataSetChanged(); 
or you can also use
listview.invalidateViews();
```

Edit:

```
add this line in (convertView == null) {} block.
clearView.setTag(position); then,

clearView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        listItems.remove(v.getTag());
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

Comment: the problem with using position is that it will always be at the last position of the listView.

Comment: ohk, then try to set position as a tag on clearView button and use it to remove list item, see i have edited my answer again.

Comment: my main problem is that no matter what value I put in remove(), it will always delete the last row. I'm thinking I setup the listView wrong somehow